# MySQL replication throught SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, ssh, replication, tunnel

I am having trouble setting up the replication via `SSH` tunnel despite many hours spent throught the official docs, articles and SO questions.

My master is `192.168.0.105` and the Slave is `192.168.0.104`. I have already set up the SSH tunnel via:

```
ssh -L 3305:127.0.0.1:3306 tunneluser@192.168.0.105 -f -N
```

where `tunneluser` is a local user on my **master**.

I get the following output on a slave (omitted the irrelevant lines):

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
                  Master_User: slave_user
                  Master_Port: 3305
                  ...
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
                  ...
                Last_IO_Errno: 2003
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'slave_user@127.0.0.1:3305' - retry-time: 10  retries: 1
                  ...
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The part that puzzles me is that if I try:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3305 -u slave_user -p
```

It logs-in without any issues. I am beginning to think this has something to do with permissions, but I cannot find any hint to confirm my theory.

I tried to setup the tunnel as `mysql` user, however, that did not work as well. Didn't really expect but I had to give it a shot.

**Does anyone have any suggestion on how to debug this?**

If I go directly through port `3306`, it works without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after several days, I found a similar question on ServerFault:

**[MySQL Replication Over SSH - Last_IO_Errno: 2003 - error connecting to master](https://serverfault.com/questions/529259/mysql-replication-over-ssh-last-io-errno-2003-error-connecting-to-master)**

It turned out `SELinux` had to do everything with this! As **@Tek Jau** explained, you can tackle this by adding this custom port via `semanage`:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/semanage port -a -t mysqld_port_t -p tcp 3305
```

Hope this helps anyone who stumbles upon similar issue.