# MySQL master-slave replication connection failure

Tags: mysql, ssh-tunnel, master-slave

I'm trying to setup replication of a very simple database located on a MySQL8.0 installation on a computer running Scientific Linux release 6.10 (Carbon). The slave computer has Mysql 5.7.18 on a CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core).

The slave computer has no direct access to the master computer, so I use ssh port forwarding to get around that. The mysql command below on the slave computer works:

```
 ssh -g -R 8899:127.0.0.1:3306 username@intermediate_computer
 ssh -g -R 8899:127.0.0.1:8899 username@slave_computer
 mysql -u repl_user -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 8899
 connect testdb;
mysql> select * from table1;
+----+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | name               | tag                 | reference |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|  1 | apple              | good                |         4 |
|  2 | watermelon         | garden good         |         5 |
|  3 | early girl tomatos | red,excellent       |         8 |
|  4 | golden boy tomatos | yellow,excellent    |         8 |
|  5 | green beans        | green,tasty         |         7 |
|  6 | kale               | green,mildly bitter |         3 |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

However, the slave cannot connect to the master using the same port:

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
                  Master_User: repl_user
                  Master_Port: 8899
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File:
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 4
               Relay_Log_File: cdms-db-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File:
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: testdb
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 0
              Relay_Log_Space: 154
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 2003
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'repl_user@127.0.0.1:8899' - retry-time: 60  retries: 28
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 0
                  Master_UUID:
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 201031 10:17:26
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set: a1932c42-9d74-11e7-ba23-0015175696ac:1-8
                Auto_Position: 1
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

my.cnf on the master:

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
relay_log_space_limit=8000000000
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
#log_warnings = 2

# Information added by to set this as a master for replication
server-id=2
log-bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_format=row
gtid-mode=ON
enforce-gtid-consistency=ON
```

my.cnf on the slave:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

#skip-grant-tables

max_allowed_packet = 64M

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid


# Information added to set this as a slave for test replication 
gtid_mode=ON
enforce-gtid-consistency=ON
server-id=3
skip-slave-start=ON
replicate-do-db=testdb
log-slave-updates=ON
```

Any help understanding why the slave appears to not talk to the master would be greatly appreciated. I spent a couple hours looking for all similar questions and none seem to be close enough to help.

Here is the grant status on the master database:

```
mysq>show grants;
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for repl_user@127.0.0.1                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO `repl_user`@`127.0.0.1`        |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testdb`.* TO `repl_user`@`127.0.0.1` |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Have you considered looking up MySQL error 2003?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have read every post that I can find about the error message. None of them related sufficiently to my situation to help.

Comment: I didn't say anything about reading posts. You should look it up in the MySQL reference materal. You need to start using the official documentation and stop relying on random searches. I found out what 2003 means in less than 30 seconds. You can too.

Comment: I appreciate that you took the time to comment. However, I have been over the MySQL reference materials (repeatedly). The description does not help for several reasons. (1) The error message described in the reference materials does not match the one I posted (error connecting to master). (2) I read through and followed the MySQL replication instructions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-howto.html They result in the same error message.

After > 10 hours of searching, I still have no idea why the connection does not work. The credentials used are correct.

Comment: The only report of an issue that seems like the issue I face is this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923220/mysql-replication-throught-ssh-tunnel However, semanage is not enabled on the server holding the master.

Comment: I'm left wondering if MySQL is trying to use a socket rather than a tcp port for an unknown reason. The master's mysql.log shows Connect   repl_user@localhost on  using SSL/TLS even if I connect using --protocol=TCP on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Can you try to login master mysql node by below cli method: **mysql -urepl_user -pPASSWORD -h 127.0.0.1 -P8899**

Comment: Yes. I am able to login to the master MySQL node as you described.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `MySQL replication` over `SSH tunel`. Here is a [nice-to-read](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-mysql-replication-using-ssh-on-a-vps) guide on how to achieve that. It points out the steps needed for the replication, how to set up users on both servers, configure `MySQL` and more.

To create a SSH tunnel use the following command. (slave)

```
ssh -L 8899:127.0.0.1:3306 ssh_tunnel_user@master_server_ip_address -f -N
```

**EDIT**

Or you could try the following changes/additions:

Create a `repl_user` like this:

```
mysql> CREATE USER repl_user@X.X.X.X; // where X.X.X.x is the external ip of the master server
```

Grant replication permission

```
mysql > GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO repl_user@X.X.X.X IDENTIFIED BY 'mysecurepass';
```

To allow port `3306` in your firewall rules you would need something like this. (You could try this first...)

```
# firewall-cmd --new-zone=mysql_replication_access --permanent
# firewall-cmd --reload
# firewall-cmd --get-zones // check that your zone exists
# firewall-cmd --zone=mysql_replication_access --add-source=Y.Y.Y.Y/Y --permanent // Y.Y.Y.Y/Y client server ip address or range
# firewall-cmd --zone=mysql_replication_access --add-port=3306/tcp  --permanent
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

But in your case you also need port forwarding which is created by your firewall rules for your specific zone as listed above.

So i think something like the following firewall rule, is most probably needed.

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent –zone=mysql_replication_access --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="X.X.X.X" forward-port to-addr="Y.Y.Y.Y" to-port="8899" protocol="tcp" port="3306"'
```

Some more ideas you could get from:

- [Configuring Complex Firewall Rules with the "Rich Language" Syntax](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/configuring_complex_firewall_rules_with_the_rich-language_syntax)
- [Using Zones to Manage Incoming Traffic Depending on Source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using_zones_to_manage_incoming_traffic_depending_on_source)
- [Whitelist source IP addresses in CentOS 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159873/whitelist-source-ip-addresses-in-centos-7)

Comment: Thank you! That webpage would have saved me immense time in figuring out the SSH tunnel. I believe my tunnel is comparable (but doesn't use a key pair) because my setup passes the connectivity test given at the end of the guide (see code below). However, the slave has an error connecting to master using the same credentials. The failure modes mention elsewhere (too long of a password or username and SElinux are not the case for me).
`code`
Connectivity can be tested from the slave using the following command: (slave)

mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u slave_user -P 33061 -p `code`

Comment: @user1621123 There is one more thing, you might need to check. In the last two lines in your question, are the commands for setting the privileges of `repl_user`. It might be needed to add the same two lines but this time using the wildcard character `%` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Apologies for the slow response. I tried adding the same 2 lines of privileges for repl_user but using the wildcard character %. The result is the same error message. I've managed to get another 5.7.32 MySQL server installed on another machine that doesn't need the ssh tunnel to try to split the potential sources of trouble into MySQL master/slave and ssh tunnels. Right now that fails with a 1236 error which I'm investigating but haven't investigated far enough to ask for help.

Comment: @user1621123 some ideas on the error you can get here https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/10/08/mysql-replication-got-fatal-error-1236-causes-and-cures/

Comment: @user1621123 by changing the wild character to `%` you should also allow incoming connections in `3306` in your firewall. To allow only for the ip address of the slave you need something like ` CREATE USER repl_user@X.X.X.X;` and `GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO repl_user@X.X.X.X IDENTIFIED BY 'mysecurepass';`.

Comment: @user1621123 check the edit. Where was my mind mate... Skip the `ssh` tunnel part or this solution. You are port forwarding. Set up the proper rules in your firewall (this might need both slave and master)

Comment: @petergd To make progress, I've tried to setup the simplest replication possible not using any ssh tunnels and fully (I hope) documented the resuling 1236 error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64773739/how-do-i-address-a-mysql-replication-slave-error-1236 Once this works, I'll try incorporating an ssh tunnel into the working replication.

Comment: @user1621123 see the notes in the lower section of this article specially the `skip-networking` part https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto-masterbaseconfig.html

Comment: On both master and replica it shows: ```>SHOW VARIABLES where Variable_name='skip_networking';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| skip_networking | OFF   |
+-----------------+-------+```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it, but either I don't understand you setting or this :

```
ssh -g -R 8899:127.0.0.1:3306 username@intermediate_computer
ssh -g -R 8899:127.0.0.1:8899 username@slave_computer
```

mean you try to bind the same internal port `8899` on two different output `3306` and `8899`. This seem problematic to me, have you tried 2 different port ?

Comment: The ssh lines port forward the MySQL default port 3306 to port 8899 on the intermediate computer and then from there to port 8899 on the computer hosting the slave database. The computer on which the slave database does not have direct access to the computer hosting the master database. I'll note that entering "mysql -u username -h 127.0.0.1 -P 8899 -p" in a terminal on the slave computer does work to connect to the master database.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience with working with mysql replication I can tell you that slave mysql version must be the same as master or higher. As I can see you're using 8.0 on master and 5.7 on slave one.

In your case, the master may pass binlogs that slave cannot understand.

Comment: I have been concerned about the same. I have been able to start a 3rd MySQL database to use as master. This third database is 5.7.32. The slave is 5.7.18. The same issue remains. I'll try to reverse master and slave to see if it persists.