# How do I address a MySQL replication slave error 1236

Tags: mysql, replication

This question follows up on my prior (unresolved) one: [MySQL master-slave replication connection failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624609/mysql-master-slave-replication-connection-failure)

I decided to setup the simplest replication possible following https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-configuration.html. The idea is get anything working and then incrementally change to the needed settings. Cliff notes version: a 1236 error occurs. The end of this question lists why common sources of 1236 errors do not seem to be applicable.

The master is MySQL 5.7.32 and is used only by me for this replication test. The replication database is `testdb` where `testdb` is the simplest possible. It contains no tables or data. The same issue occurs when `testdb` contains one simple table with 5 rows each consisting of 2 short VARCHARs and 2 INTs.

Replica is MySQL 8.0.

replication user: `repl_user`
repl_user permission on `master`:

```
mysql> select host,user,Repl_slave_priv,Repl_client_priv from mysql.user where user='repl_user';
+---------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| host                            | user      | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv |
+---------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| 127.0.0.1                       | repl_user | Y               | N                |
| localhost                       | repl_user | Y               | N                |
| %                               | repl_user | Y               | N                |
| slave_ip                        | repl_user | Y               | N                |
+---------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
```

I can log into the master MySQL from the replica computer:

```
>mysql -u repl_user -h master_ip -p -P 3306
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 15
Server version: 5.7.32-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Dumped the relevant database on the master:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --databases testdb --master-data > master_testdb_dump20201110.sql
```

Inserted it in the replica:

```
mysql -u root -p < master_testdb_dump20201110.sql
```

On the master:

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File              | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysqld-bin.000002 |      488 |              |                  |                   |
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

```
mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
+-------------------+-----------+
| Log_name          | File_size |
+-------------------+-----------+
| mysqld-bin.000001 |       177 |
| mysqld-bin.000002 |       488 |
+-------------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

On the replica:

```
    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='master_ip', MASTER_USER='repl_user', MASTER_PASSWORD='correct password', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000002', MASTER_LOG_POS=488, master_port=3306;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)
    start replica;
    show replica status\G
    *************************** 1. row ***************************
                 Replica_IO_State:
                      Source_Host: host_ip
                      Source_User: repl_user
                      Source_Port: 3306
                    Connect_Retry: 60
                  Source_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
              Read_Source_Log_Pos: 488
                   Relay_Log_File: replica_name-relay-bin.000001
                    Relay_Log_Pos: 4
            Relay_Source_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
               Replica_IO_Running: No
              Replica_SQL_Running: Yes
                  Replicate_Do_DB:
              Replicate_Ignore_DB:
               Replicate_Do_Table:
           Replicate_Ignore_Table:
          Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                       Last_Errno: 0
                       Last_Error:
                     Skip_Counter: 0
              Exec_Source_Log_Pos: 488
                  Relay_Log_Space: 156
                  Until_Condition: None
                   Until_Log_File:
                    Until_Log_Pos: 0
               Source_SSL_Allowed: No
               Source_SSL_CA_File:
               Source_SSL_CA_Path:
                  Source_SSL_Cert:
                Source_SSL_Cipher:
                   Source_SSL_Key:
            Seconds_Behind_Source: NULL
    Source_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                    Last_IO_Errno: 13114
                    Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'
                   Last_SQL_Errno: 0
                   Last_SQL_Error:
      Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
                 Source_Server_Id: 4
                      Source_UUID: e4e01e90-1e22-11eb-84b1-0015175ac510
                 Source_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                        SQL_Delay: 0
              SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
        Replica_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
               Source_Retry_Count: 86400
                      Source_Bind:
          Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 201110 07:53:50
         Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
                   Source_SSL_Crl:
               Source_SSL_Crlpath:
               Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
                Executed_Gtid_Set:
                    Auto_Position: 0
             Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                     Channel_Name:
               Source_TLS_Version:
           Source_public_key_path:
            Get_Source_public_key: 0
                Network_Namespace:
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The Relay_Log_File does exist on the replica and is a non-empty binary file.

I did a tail -f on /var/log/mysql/mysql.log on both the master and replica:

Replica log:

```
2020-11-10T15:58:04.075427Z        11 Query     CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = 'master_ip', MASTER_USER = 'repl_user', MASTER_PASSWORD = <secret>, MASTER_PORT = 3306, MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin.000002', MASTER_LOG_POS = 488
2020-11-10T15:58:07.411303Z        11 Query     start replica
2020-11-10T15:58:07.413325Z        12 Connect Out       repl_user@master_ip:3306
2020-11-10T15:58:10.750305Z        11 Query     show replica status
```

Master log:

```
2020-11-10T15:58:07.413034Z        20 Connect   repl_user@replica_ip on  using TCP/IP
2020-11-10T15:58:07.413483Z        20 Query     SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
2020-11-10T15:58:07.413744Z        20 Query     SELECT @@GLOBAL.SERVER_ID
2020-11-10T15:58:07.413935Z        20 Query     SET @master_heartbeat_period= 30000001024
2020-11-10T15:58:07.414132Z        20 Query     SET @master_binlog_checksum= @@global.binlog_checksum
2020-11-10T15:58:07.414321Z        20 Query     SELECT @master_binlog_checksum
2020-11-10T15:58:07.414529Z        20 Query     SELECT @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE
2020-11-10T15:58:07.414731Z        20 Query     SELECT @@GLOBAL.SERVER_UUID
2020-11-10T15:58:07.414917Z        20 Query     SET @slave_uuid= 'a1932c42-9d74-11e7-ba23-0015175696ac'
2020-11-10T15:58:07.415394Z        20 Binlog Dump       Log: 'mysql-bin.000002'  Pos: 488
2020-11-10T16:05:39.836945Z        14 Query     select host,user,Repl_slave_priv,Repl_client_priv from mysql.user where user='repl_user'
```

Master my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
server-id=4
log-bin=mysqld-bin
bind-address=0.0.0.0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog=1
max_allowed_packet=64M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
user=mysql
skip-slave-start
```

Replica my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
server-id=1
log-bin=mysqld-bin
bind-address=0.0.0.0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog=1
max_allowed_packet=64M
skip-slave-start

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
user=mysql
```

***Addressing possible failure modes***

@petergd pointed out https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/10/08/mysql-replication-got-fatal-error-1236-causes-and-cures/ on possible 1236 causes and cures. (I've read many other pages too and MySQL documentation; I spend a couple days on this one simple setup.)

1. `max_allowed_packet` is set uniformly on both master and replica. 64M is the default value and greatly exceeds the largest row (as there are no rows of data).
2. "This error occurs when the slave server required binary log for replication no longer exists on the master database server." The above posts demonstrate that the binary log does exist. I've also manually verified the existence of `mysqld-bin.000002` by issuing a `ls /var/lib/mysql`
3. Missing binary files doesn't seem to be the case. Log expiration is not enabled in my.cnf. `Source_Log_File` is present on the server in the `/var/lib/mysql` directory. `Relay_Log_File` and
   `Relay_Source_Log_File` are present on the replica in the `/var/lib/mysql` directory.

Comment: What do you get as output from this on `master` `show variables like "%skip%networking%";`

Comment: Both server and replica show the value to be OFF.

Comment: Following something close to the advice here (https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/9sgmee/mysql_replication_master_slave/), I did: on replica: ```stop replica; reset replica;``` On master: ```reset master;``` On replica: ```change master...;start replica;```. The second time I did this, the replication began working.

Comment: That is a really interesting link (reddit) you provided.